# Image processing how to detect specific custom shape in image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I want to detect a specific shape which is combination of 2 shapes Pentagon and a square. However side of a square should be around 3 times of a pentagon to match a valid shape as shown in the image.

[image]

I'm learning different image processing techniques for my requirement.

1. Contour Detection: Issue is knowing there are 7 corners is not enough as x : 3x need to be validated.
2. Haar features: Issue is images consist of background and there are text inside these object. So haar will not optimal method in my opinion.

My idea

I think may be I can detect lines corners and using side lengths I can do some math and identify the image.Is there any image processing technique that use mathematical distance, scale, location to identify object?

Original image

matching

[image]

not matching

[image]

Comment: Can you add your original input image without the markings? A simple approach is to use corner detection + contour area filtering

Comment: @nathancy i added a image basically it's a business card .i want to detect this shape.can you explain a bit.seems interesting

Comment: Is there is another image with the "no match" shape?

Comment: @nathancy yes added.basically i want to ignore this card from the detection

Comment: Yeah so the corner detection approach didn't really work out. An alternative method that seemed to work was using contour approximation + contour area filtering. I added a possible solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load image, convert to grayscale, [Gaussian blur](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization).
2. **Filter for desired contour.** We [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) then filter using a combination of [contour approximation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) + [contour area](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea). With the observation that the shapes have a large area difference, we can use a predetermined threshold area to identify between the two.

---

Input `->` Binary image `->` Detected shape

[image]
[image]
[image]

Result

```
Match
```

Input `->` Binary image `->` Detected shape

[image]
[image]
[image]

Result

```
No Match
```

Since you didn't specify a language, I implemented in Python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsus threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    # Filter using contour approximation and area filtering (Remove small noise)
    if len(approx) > 4 and len(approx) < 8 and area > 200:
        # This is the larger version
        if area >= 5500:
            print('Match')
        # Smaller version
        elif area < 5500:
            print('No Match')
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,0,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: this is really interesting i will test the code.thanks

Comment: i'm facing small issue here.is there anyway to avoid false detection .for example this shape is nothing like requred shape but it's been detected https://imgur.com/uGsCrXT